# How to set vertical filled progress

Tags: android, progress-bar

I want to set the custom circular progress-bar like below:

[image]

---

### EDITED

I wrote following code for this. But it is not work properly :

```
private void circularProgressBar(ImageView iv2, int i) {


        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b); 
        Paint paint = new Paint();

            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#c4c4c4"));
            paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            canvas.drawCircle(150, 150, 140, paint);

            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFDB4C"));
            paint.setStrokeWidth(10);   
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            final RectF oval = new RectF();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            oval.set(10,10,290,290);

            canvas.drawArc(oval, 270, ((i*360)/100), false, paint);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(0);    
          // paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#8E8E93")); 
          //  paint.setTextSize(140);

           // canvas.drawText(""+i, 150, 150+(paint.getTextSize()/3), paint); 

            iv2.setImageBitmap(b);
    }
```

Comment: Please write the proper comment before downvoating...!!!

Comment: https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs  check it out.

Comment: I've downvoted and voted to close the question because you're just asking someone to do your work for you. You shown zero effort and explain very little of your actual goals. Either the question is not very well formulated or you don't understand very well how StackOverflow is meant to work. I hope that is a proper comment for you,

Comment: Now edited the question, Please let me know, If anything else has been left.

Comment: I very strongly suggest you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask good questions. As it stands, this one is not likely to receive interesting answers. For instance, "it is not work properly" gives no indication of what doesn't work, the actual and expected outcome, and makes it very difficult for others to know what your problem actually is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Everyone for force me to do R&D and find out the solution...

Following code is the solution of the given question

XML

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagegreenid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/clip_full_green_gauge" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagewhiteid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/clip_feil_empty_gauge" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Code in Activity:

```
int total_percent = orininalScore * 100;
int TOTAL_VALUE = 10000;

ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagegreenid);
ClipDrawable mImageDrawable = (ClipDrawable) img.getDrawable();
mImageDrawable.setLevel(total_percent);
ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagewhiteid);
ClipDrawable mImageDrawable1 = (ClipDrawable) img1.getDrawable();
mImageDrawable1.setLevel(TOTAL_VALUE - total_percent);
```